# wordpress template page doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, templates

I'm trying to create my own theme, called "Conservatoire". 
For that I've first added the style.css with these informations :

```
/*
Theme Name: Conservatoire
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/
Description: Conservatoire
Author: Thoma Biguères
Version: 1.0
Tags: black, blue, white, two-columns, fixed-width, custom-header, custom-background,     threaded-comments, sticky-post, translation-ready, microformats, rtl-language-support, editor-style, custom-menu (optional)

License:
License URI:

General comments (optional).
*/
```

So nothing too tricky here i think. 
After that I added two files. An index.php :

```
<?php
/**
* The main template file.
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Conservatoire
*/

get_header(); ?>

<!-- Add your site or application content here -->    

<!-- JavaScript at the bottom for fast page loading: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom -->

<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if offline -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<!-- scripts concatenated and minified via build script -->
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<!-- end scripts -->

<!-- Asynchronous Google Analytics snippet. Change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID.
     mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-analytics-snippet -->
<script>
    var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
    (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
    g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Until here everything works. After that, I added a front-page.php which is my static home page :

```
<?php
/**
* The template for displaying Front page.
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Conservatoire
*/

get_header(); ?>

<?php
$page = get_page_by_title('Accueil');
?>
```

Everything is still fine. 
And now things are tricky. I'm trying to add a category-{slug}.php page. So I've created a page category-membre.php which looks fine for me :

```
<?php
/**
* T he template for displaying Front page.
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Conservatoire
*/

get_header(); ?>

<ul>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li class="cadre">
    <div class="imageCadre">
        <?php echo(get_image());?>
    </div>
    <h4><?php echo(get_the_title());?></h4>
    <p><?php echo(get('information_globales_petite_description'));?></p>
    <a href="" class="plusinfo">Lire la suite</a>

</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- post navigation -->
<?php else: ?>
<!-- no posts found -->
<?php endif; ?>


</ul>
</body>
</html>
?>
```

But when I try to go on the page "localhost/Site/category/membre then I find myself on the 404 page ...

Does someone has any idea ?

Thanks

EDIT : I didn't changed the permanent link so category base is empty (i guess it's category then isn't it ? )

Here this one was my httaccess but I deleted it and it still gives me the same error :

NEW EDIT : this is the actual .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Sites/Association%20CNMP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Sites/Association%20CNMP/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Sounds like a permalink issue. Might be worth describing your current configuration (`.htaccess` and permalink pattern, at least)?

Comment: Hey, I've just edited my code with what you've asked

Comment: Yep, didn't saw that, but still doesn't change :s

Comment: And the weird thing is that it's ok for the front-page.php ...

Comment: It looks like you aren't actually rewriting your URLs. In the case you've got, WP parameters will be passed via a query string (`?param1=foo&param2=bar`), meaning that `/category/membre` will *not* be passed to the WP front controller. There's a pretty thorough walk through of setting up "pretty" links in the wordpress codex at http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna look this, I'll tell you after. 

By the way my htaccess file is not the one written above, in fact the one created by wordpress is the one in my new EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey thanks for everything,

I managed to make permalinks work. I don't really know how thoug.I know I had to set mod_rewrite of the httdconfig of apache to Ok (erase the # before the Launch mod_rewrite). And after that do some stuff. There is one thing i don't understand though !

How come my actual htaccess looks like this :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Sites/AssociationCNMP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Sites/AssociationCNMP/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

but is actually working with cat/membre ? 
I don't see the cat in the htaccess file. So how can he know he has to go to another one ?

Thanks for your help